# Why Dialogfragment showing the alert dialog twice?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying to show an alert dialog when internet goes.Everything works fine but the dialog is showing twice (overlapping one over other). why the dialog is showing twice even i am checking if the dialog instance is null before showing.Below is the code i have written.

Here is the code written in activity.

```
BroadcastReceiver networkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnected();
        if (isConnected) {
            internetAvailable();
        } else {
            showNoInternetPopup();
        }
    }
};

protected abstract void internetAvailable();

protected void showNoInternetPopup() {
    SimpleAlertDialog alertDialog = new SimpleAlertDialog();
    alertDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "1001");
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, filter);
}
```

Here is the dialog class extending dialogFragment

```
public class SimpleAlertDialog extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Your network seems to be unavailable")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();

}

@Override
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    if (manager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
        super.show(manager, tag);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue that u r getting a *double* callback form the OS.
Log it to double verify.
If its really the case then u need to handle the popup yourself so u wont dusplay twice, save the alert dialog as a member and then call *isShown()* on it. Of course chekc if its null.

Comment: Yes , I am getting double callback but why ? I am checking the condition as well

 if (manager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
        super.show(manager, tag);
    }

it should not be null once its created.

Comment: The reason for that is because u registered twice? at teh manifest and at the activity? Or its just operating system issue

Comment: U need to check prior to the fragment whether to create it. Becuase u r creating TWO fragments but show one. That is bad practice, check prior to that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by unregistering receiver on onPause.. silly me